# Is it possible to configure OpenERP or my browser to open PDFs automatically?

Tags: pdf, browser, odoo

Every OpenERP web report ask me if I want to keep the PDF. Of course I must keep it to view it. I end up with lots of PDF files that I have to clean up. I would like to configure OpenERP or my browser to automatically create and manage the temp PDF files.

My research shows me great confusion in the industry about security flaws in PDF files causing browser plugins that profess to being "PDF Viewers" to come and go. I have yet to find any method, procedure, plugin, add-on or magic incantation that views PDFs without me managing the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox and linux , why not open firefox & go to

Edit -> preferences -> applications ->

search for 'pdf' and in Action field select 'use(default)'.

This way the pdf will be stored in '/tmp' folder & opened from there.
You won't have to bother about managing it.

Comment: Firefox Edit, Preferences, Applications, PDF; "Use Document Viewer (default)" causes the Opening dialog to appear and question what to do. "Save File" causes a download but no open or view.

Comment: Your response Jibin got me thinking and I installed [acroread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11946841&postcount=4) but got the same behavior as Document Viewer.

Comment: I've gone on to try xpdf, ViewPDF and back to evince (Document Viewer) all with the same results. Each PDF viewing program requires answering keep-this-file questions.

Comment: You are using linux ?If so which distro ?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu version 12.10.

Comment: There should be some thing wrong with the firefox settings.Try deleting .mozilla/firefox folder (Its a hidden folder) inside your home folder.Take backup first.

Comment: Thanks Jibin, but; this same problem exists on 5 different Ubuntu version 12.10 (and earlier) systems. Does it work for you? If so, please tell me more about your configuration.

Comment: Jibin, can you tell me more about how it works for you? What platform version are you using?

Comment: Go to section with heading 'Reset download actions' in the following link.  
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-without-downloading-them#os=linux&browser=fx17

Comment: install the following addon
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/

Comment: Add-on PDF Viewer 0.7.1 installed and enabled. I get the same behavior "Opening Invoices.pdf which is a: PDF document from http://localhost:55700 What should Firefox do with this file? Open with Adobe Reader 9 (deafult), Save File, Do this automatically (enabled.)" Other option to "Open with" is evince.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in a clean way, you need a module that modifies the behaviour of openerp reports to be inline. There are two options:

- https://github.com/buke/openerp-web-pdf-preview-print - I think this
  is the best option as it works all the time, the caveat is it
  launches a separated window like a popup (then you require to accept
  popups).
- https://www.openerp.com/apps/web_pdf_viewer - This is amazing as it
  shows the pdf in the work area of openerp (no need to open a new tab
  or a new window) but at the moment doesn't work at all times,some
  reports are just downloaded instead of displayed (I dunno why).

BR

Andres Calle

www.trescloud.com